# Cannot call method 'findOne' of undefined at Object.module.exports

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Need to knoe why I'mgetting this error? is my approach for validating the user thorugh login form correct here? I'm just new to node.js need your help.

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/subscribe');

var mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id : String,
    name : String,
    phone : String,
    age : Number,
   password : String
   });

 var User = mongoose.model('signups', mySchema);
```

Signup form , to save the registered user in the mongodb collection.

```
router.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
   var user = new User({
       _id : req.body.email,
   phone : req.body.phone,
   age : req.body.age,
   password : req.body.password
});
user.save(function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
    res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
}
else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});
});
```

trying to validate the user credentials

```
router.post('/adduser',function(req, res){
db.signups.findOne({ $and: [{_id: req.body.useremail}, {password: req.body.password }]}, function(err, item) {  
    if (err) return res.send("Please provide valid credentials.");
else {
    res.redirect('/home');
    }
});
});
```

How to validate the user credentials here?

Comment: Your model as defined above is called `User`. You actually need to call the method on that model, not under the `db.collection` type of syntax you may be used to from the shell.

Comment: Thanks for your response..but when i use Model with findOne method it doesn't validate the users. Simply takes me to the home page.. User.findOne({ $and: [{_id: 'req.param.useremail'}, {password: '$req.param.password'}]}, function(err, item) { ...}

Comment: And empty response is not the same as an error. You need to make sure you actually received something.

Comment: Slightly offtopic -- you may have left out some code relevant to the auth, but just in case: for the sake of everyone that will ever use your service, please do not store plain text passwords. Thanks!